# how to get simple count & group by in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

assuming I have a data that has two categories, for example - football or basketball, where football value is 1 and basketball value is 2, and we have the following data:

```
_id    game
'1'      1
'2'      1
'3'      2
'4'      1
'5'      2
```

(the data contains football 3 times and basketball 2 times).
I want to perform an aggregation that returns the following object:

```
{
   footballCount: 3,
   basketballCount: 2
}
```

I can't think of such an aggregation that results in such structure.
How can I do that?

Comment: Is [this conditional sum](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0TjKcfBqY25) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a conditional sum for different cases.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      footballCount: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$game",
                1
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      basketballCount: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$game",
                2
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0TjKcfBqY25) for your reference.